# Http failure during parsing in angular 7

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a kendo drop down and trying to call an api when the user tries to search by entering characters. I can see that the call is being made to the api and the api is returning the filtered values however the data is not getting bound.

I can see that an error occurs and the err block is executed . The error states that

Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:54455/fund/HFRFundSearch?term=as

Could somebody tell me what the issue is . Is it because the api is returning an object

Here is my code

```
 <label for="inputFax" class="col-md-2  col-form-label header">Third Party Database Feed</label>
 <div class="col-md-3">
       <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FundDetails.HFRFundName}}</div>
         <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:350px" [(ngModel)]="HFRFunds" [data]="HFRFunds"  [filterable]="true" [valuePrimitive]="true"   textField="text" valueField="id"  (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)"></kendo-dropdownlist>
 </div>
```

component

```
 handleFilter(value) {
        if (value.length >= 2) {
            this.fundService.getHFRFund(value)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.HFRFunds = data;
            },
                err => {
                    this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
                },
                () => {
                });
        }
    }
```

service

```
 constructor(
            private http: HttpClient,
            private config: AppConfig)
    { }

 getHFRFund(value : string) {
                let pars = new HttpParams();
                pars = pars.append('term', value.toString());
                const url = this.config.api.hfrFundSearch;
                return this.http.get(url, { params: pars, withCredentials: true });
        }
```

api.

```
[HttpGet]
        [AuthorizationLevel(AuthAccessLevel.Read)]
        public object HFRFundSearch(string term)
        {
            try
            {
                var hfrFunds = new List<object>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                {
                    term = term.ToLower();
                    hfrFunds.AddRange(GetViewService<V_HFR_FUND>()
                        .Where(x => x.HFR_FUND_NAME.ToLower().StartsWith(term))
                        .Take(10)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.HFR_FUND_NAME)
                        .Select(x => new { id = x.HFR_FUND_ID, text = x.HFR_FUND_NAME })
                        .ToList());
                }

                return hfrFunds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to return an IActionResult from the c# controller?

Comment: Can you console.log data inside of your subscribe?  You can try to use pipe and map in your component (in my answer below)...

Answer (score 0):

```
// API
[HttpGet]
        [AuthorizationLevel(AuthAccessLevel.Read)]
        public object HFRFundSearch(string term)
        {
            try
            {
                var hfrFunds = new List<object>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                {
                    term = term.ToLower();
                    hfrFunds.AddRange(GetViewService<V_HFR_FUND>()
                        .Where(x => x.HFR_FUND_NAME.ToLower().StartsWith(term))
                        .Take(10)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.HFR_FUND_NAME)
                        .Select(x => new { value = x.HFR_FUND_ID, text = x.HFR_FUND_NAME })
                        .ToList());
                }

                return hfrFunds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex);
                return ex;
            }
        }


    // component
     // component
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    handleFilter(value) {            
       if (value.length >= 2) {                     
          this.fundService.getHFRFund(value).subscribe(
                data => {
                 this.HRFunds = data;
           });           
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be calling the api as the breakpoint isnt getting hit. The old method calls the api

Comment: Is it because I am not calling subscribe

Comment: I am not too familiar with how Kendo implements Angular but is there a filterChanges method in your component?  Here is a link for Kendo's API for dropdown lists and Angular (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/)

Comment: I dont think the issue that i mentioned got to do with kendo. The api wasnt getting called with the proposed map code

Comment: Can you console.log inside of your handleFilter method?  Is the value.length >= 2?

Comment: yes the console.log outputs the value. So i can see that the if statement gets satisfied. After the pipe line is executed, nothing happens

Comment: It looks like the API is returning an object of type { id, text } and the control is looking for an object of type { value, text }.  I have updated my answer... can you try that?